# .NET When is a task considered as faulted?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am new to TPL and I am wondering, when you have a like this:

```
Task.Run(() =>{
  // Some code here to call several APIs...
});
```

When is this task considered as faulted ? When their is an exception thrown inside, that is not caught ?

And can you manually set this Task to faulted ? For example if you catch an exception, you want this task to be faulted, so that continuation tasks are not executed ?

Thank you for all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exceptions cause to get the failed state (except when `OperationCancelledException` is thrown, then it's `IsCanceled` property becomes true).

You can't set Task directly to faulted, except when using [TaskCompletitionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1) source directly with the `.SetException` method.

But what is your issue with throwing the exception? After handling the exception you can just throw it

```
Task.Run(() =>{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        logging.Error("Something went wrong", ex);

        // rethrow the same exception. 
        // Don't do: "throw ex" as it changes stack trace, making debugging harder
        throw;
    }
});
```

Alternatively use C# 6.0's [when language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when#when-in-a-catch-statement) construct to perform logging.

```
Task.Run(() =>{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex) when (LogException(ex))
    {
    }
});

...
private bool LogException(ex)
{
    logging.Error("Something went wrong", ex);

    // returning true means, exception block will be executed
    // returning false means, exception block won't be executed
    return false;
}
```

This way, the logging will be performed, but the exception itself won't be caught (and be caught by the waiting Task.